# Google bigquery for free?

Tags: google-bigquery, temboo

Im new here and looking actually for this:
https://temboo.com/hardware/google-big-query-getting-started

Its going about how to connect Sensors to Google Bigquery,
but I actually don't know whether it is free or not.
My usage per month were around 1GB.
Please tell me what I can get for free there, I'm absolutely beginner and don't want get a big bill.

Thanks,
Petr

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery charges for query processing and storage.

Query processing will likely be free in your case, since the first 1 TB per month is free, and you're only using 1 GB per month.

You will likely to have pay a small amount to store the data you're querying, but at that scale we're talking pennies ($0.02/GB/month).

Full pricing details:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing

Comment: Do I can not store the data in my Google drive ?

Comment: No, you need to store data in BigQuery storage or Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Exist a alternative to Bigquery ? Where a low amount like 100MB are for free ?

Comment: s.o. is not for asking tool recomendacions.

Comment: 100 MB in BigQuery is $0.002/month. That's practically free. :-)